# Automating number of paid sick days employee has remaining

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a file showing how many paid sick days an employee has remaining, we get five days each on a rolling 365 day basis. So if someone is sick 24/05/16, 25/05/16, 26/05/16, 27/05/16, 28/05/16, they'll get paid for those 5 days. They will not be paid if they are sick on any day between 28/05/16 and 23/05/17. And if they are not sick from 24-28/05/16, they are re-entitled to their 5 days again.

We have a calendar of 365 days and we fill it in when someone is sick, then check how many days they have been sick in the past 365 days and fill in the table each time manually.

*Basically, is there a way of automating the counting how many sick days paid someone gets within a 365 day timeframe?*

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It would be helpful if you posted a sample of what your data looks like (how it is arranged). Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1094398/edit) your question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without using macros, this formula checks for you whether somebody had 5+ paid sick days in the last year:

`=IF(B3<>"",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,">="&$A3-365,C$2:C2,"=yes")>=5,"no","yes"),"")`

(note: I've just check last 365 days instead of one calendar year, you may want to use different calculation).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift answer :D Is there a way to count how many there are left from 365 days ago up to today as a number from 0-5?

Comment: yes, `COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,">="&$A3-365,C$2:C2,"=yes")` returns number of paid sickdays, so `5-COUNTIFS(...)` return what's left

Comment: Cool thanks man, did that then used VLOOKUP to view the current amount left to be put into a single cell

Comment: I'm happy it helped you. please don't forget to accept this as an answer to mark your question solved.